AWS extract IAM role with some prefix and its corresponding policing into csv file
Expected output into csv :
IAMRole1, IAMRole2, IAMRole3
Policy1-1,Policy2-1,Policy3-1
Policy1-2,Policy2-2,
Policy1-3,,


In CSV , we must have policy name and not ARN.
For each role, extract both attached policies and inline policies.
CSV Structure: The CSV file will have roles as the header row and their corresponding policies listed below each role.
Each policy is placed in the corresponding column under the role.


https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/



#!/bin/bash

PREFIX="AWSServiceRole"
OUTPUT_FILE="iam_roles_and_policies.csv"

# Function to list attached policies
list_attached_policies() {
    local role_name="$1"
    aws iam list-attached-role-policies --role-name "$role_name" --query 'AttachedPolicies[*].PolicyArn' --output text
}

# Function to extract policy name from ARN
extract_policy_name() {
    local policy_arn="$1"
    echo "$policy_arn" | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'
}

# Function to list inline policies
list_inline_policies() {
    local role_name="$1"
    aws iam list-role-policies --role-name "$role_name" --query 'PolicyNames[*]' --output text
}

# Check if AWS CLI is installed
if ! command -v aws &> /dev/null; then
    echo "AWS CLI not found. Please install AWS CLI first."
    exit 1
fi

# Get the list of IAM roles with the specified prefix
roles=$(aws iam list-roles --query "Roles[?starts_with(RoleName, \`$PREFIX\`)].RoleName" --output text)

# Check if any roles exist
if [ -z "$roles" ]; then
    echo "No IAM roles found."
    exit 1
fi

# Create or overwrite the CSV file (no header needed)
: > "$OUTPUT_FILE"

# Write the role names in the first row
for role in $roles; do
    echo "Writing role: $role"
    echo -n "$role," >> "$OUTPUT_FILE"
done
echo "" >> "$OUTPUT_FILE"  # New line after the first row

# Determine the maximum number of policies any role has (attached + inline)
printf "Calculating maximum number of policies any role has (attached + inline)\n\n\n\n"
max_policies=0
for role in $roles; do
    attached_count=$(list_attached_policies "$role" | wc -w)
    inline_count=$(list_inline_policies "$role" | wc -w)
    total_count=$((attached_count + inline_count))
    echo "Role $role : have , attached_count : $attached_count, inline_count : $inline_count,  and total_count : $total_count"
    if [ "$total_count" -gt "$max_policies" ]; then
        max_policies=$total_count
    fi
done

# Echo the maximum number of policies
printf "\n\nMaximum number of policies any role has (attached + inline): %d\n" "$max_policies"

# Write the policies under each role
for ((i=1; i<=$max_policies; i++)); do
    for role in $roles; do
        # Fetch attached and inline policies
        attached_policies=$(list_attached_policies "$role")
        inline_policies=$(list_inline_policies "$role")
        
        # Combine policies
        combined_policies=($attached_policies $inline_policies)
        
        # Get the i-th policy if it exists
        policy=${combined_policies[$((i-1))]}
        if [ -n "$policy" ]; then
            policy_name=$(extract_policy_name "$policy")
            echo "Role: $role, Policy: $policy_name"
            echo -n "$policy_name," >> "$OUTPUT_FILE"
        else
            echo "Role: $role, Policy: (none)"
            echo -n "," >> "$OUTPUT_FILE"  # Empty cell if no policy
        fi
    done
    echo "" >> "$OUTPUT_FILE"  # New line after each policy row
done

echo "IAM roles and policies have been saved to $OUTPUT_FILE"





